# jquery sortable connectWith to rails form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui-sortable

### Dear stackoverflow wizards,

My js-skills are failing me.

I have this Model called routine.rb that has an associated model called action_partials that is connected through a table called routine_actions.

I would like to be able to create a Routine and be able to select the associated action_partaials by drag and drop using jquery sortable.

```
<ul class="box-to-select-from">
  <% ActionPartial.all.each do |action| %>
    <li data-id = <%=action.id%></li>
  <% end -%>
</ul>
<ul class="box-to-drop-selected">

</ul>
```

And then submit it through a rails form and passed through the rails logic to create a new Routine with action_partials saved in the correct order. I'm all lost here as js is not my strong suit. I'd love it if someone could point me in a direction.

Comment: Like this: `<li data-id = "<%= action.id %>"></li>`

Comment: Sorry that was wrong coding by me in the example. I need help with the JS and rails backend.